# VB.NET select implementation out of an interface at runtime

Tags: vb.net, interface

Imagining in VB.NET that I have a solution called hostlink.mq

I have created a project inside it called hostlink.interfaces, another project called hostlink.activemq, and yet another called hostlink.IbmMq. The latter two implement interfaces created on hostlink.interfaces project.

That said, I need to select at runtime which implementation I want to run. Each implementation project has its own references to nuget packages specific to that implementation. On the interfaces project, I don't want to include references to the implementation projects. I need somehow to get the reference at runtime. I know that the connection factory selector code posted below doesn't work, since I don't have references to the implementations on the interface:

```
Private Function GetOrAddConnectionFactory(provider As MqProvider) As IMqConnectionFactory
If _connectionFactories.ContainsKey(provider) Then
  Return _connectionFactories(provider)
Else
  Select Case provider
    Case MqProvider.IbmMq
      _connectionFactories.Add(provider, New IbmMq.ConnectionFactory(_log))
    Case MqProvider.ActiveMq 
      _connnectionFactories.Add(provider, new ActiveMq.ConnectionFactory(_log))
  End Select
  Return _connectionFactories(provider)
End If
End Function
```

What I would like to know is how to select the correct implementation and add it at runtime to avoid having to reference them on the interface.

Another question which is related to this: one of the implementations must target 3.5 Framework since there's no nuget packages for the 4.x Framework for that implementation, while the other can be (and should be) using 4.x Framework. Can I put the interface project targeting the 4.x Framework while keeping one of the implementations targeting the 3.5 Framework? Or it must be the other way round, the interface targeting the 3.5 Framework and one of the implementations targeting the 4.0 Framework? The interface has nothing specific that needs the 4.0 Framework.

I'm not used to Visual Studio languages, in java I would use an injection framework like Spring and inject the references at runtime.

Comment: You would do basically the same in .NET as you would in Java, using [Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor/) or [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) or the like.

Comment: the dependency injection or inversion of control patterns are not specific to any particular programming language. And Spring is a general application framework, not just for doing an injection-based design

Comment: @Adyson, I know that Spring is much more than injection, I just referenced it so that people know from where I come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than using a dependency injection framework as mentioned in the comments, you can also use [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224132(v=vs.110).aspx) to load a type given it's name and the name of the containing assembly.

Regarding Question 2, I would put the interface in it's own project so that your implementations and main program can each reference the interface without needing to reference each other. If the interface is referenced by a .NET 3.5 project, then it can't be higher than .NET 3.5 itself.

Comment: Thanks PKing, I'll use the two suggestions. I didn't know that about the interface either.